# Using Selection Expression in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, select

I am trying to use the selection expression box to highlight counties by state FIPS. When I use the OR conditional all counties across the US get highlighted. So for example, `STATEFIPS = 1` will successfully highlight just counties in Alabama, as I want.

But when I do `STATEFIPS = 1 OR 12` then I get all counties across the US highlighted, not just the ones in Florida and Alabama. Is this a bug or am I doing the expression wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `"STATEFIPS = 1 OR STATEFIPS = 12"`. Your current expression is effectively `"STATEFIPS = 1) or (12)"`, and since `"12"` will always evaluate to true this results in all features being selected.

Comment: It's also handy to use `IN` instead of `OR` if you're looking for different values from the same column: `"STATEFIPS" IN (1, 12)` is a little shorter than a whole bunch of `OR` statements chained together for a single column =)